# JavaScript: Documentation for access of form, via form name

Tags: javascript

From the [HTMLFormElement MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement):

> To obtain an `HTMLFormElement` object,
>   you can use a CSS selector with `querySelector()`, or you can get a list
>   of all of the forms in the document using its forms property.
>
> `Document.forms` returns an array of `HTMLFormElement` objects listing
>   each of the forms on the page. You can then use any of the following
>   syntaxes to get an individual form:
>
> **document.forms[index]**: Returns the form at the specified index into the array of forms.
>
> **document.forms[id]**: Returns the form whose ID is id.
>
> **document.forms[name]**: Returns the form whose name attribute's value is name.

Still, it is possible to access a form element on the `document` object directly by its `name` attribute, without going via `Document.forms`:

```
let myForm = document.myFormName;
```

I have looked around the MDN WebAPI pages for a while and cannot seem to find the property that allows the above direct access. The property certainly does not seem to be on the Document or Element objects.

Any thoughts?

---

### EDIT

[Here is an example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

Note the following code, from the MDN example:

```
document.registration.accept.checked = false;
```

Comment: Did you set id same as name on `<form>`? Element ID's also become properties of `document`

Comment: Nope, only the `name` is needed apparently.

Comment: I guess the above duplicate is what you need ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, that's it, thank you. MDN should really make that clear. Not everyone has time to read through 500,000 pages of specs hehe. Thanks again.