# HTML/CSS: Input element breaks vertical-align on immediate siblings

Tags: html, css

I stumbled across a rather odd behavior of CSS. Take a look at this:

```css
span {
  line-height: 50px;
}

form label {
  line-height: initial;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

label span {
  vertical-align: top;
}

label input {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <span><label>Some label<span>foo</span><input></label></span>
</form>
```

Changing the vertical alignment works fine on "Some label" and on `input`, but any *inline box* that is an immediate sibling of an `input` element looses its ability to move vertically in its *line box*.

Try changing `vertcal-align` for `foo` (`label span`) and you will see the odd behavior. If you swap out `<input>` for any other *inline-level box*, it goes back to behaving as expected.

I tried copying all the CSS properties of `<input>` over onto `label span`, without being able to summon the same effect.

Comment: Hey Temani! Any idea on this one too, by any chance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594495/javascript-documentation-for-access-of-form-via-form-name

Comment: Well not the time to write an explained answer :p but be carefull about line-height of the inner span that is having the same line-height of the outer one

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yep, I know, I reset the inner line-heights to initial (normal). This odd behavior only occurs with `input` elements, not other *inline-level elements*.

Comment: well, am not suprised about this behavior, but I don't have all the words to explain right now, I will do when I woke up tomorrow ;) but am pretty sure you will get the answer before :p

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you remove all the styles, everything is in line. The big culprit is span's line-height. But, what?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do too!

Comment: One thing I see is you've set `form label { line-height: initial;` then the inner span gets the line-height set *again*, so both spans are getting line-height set sparately - the 1st one gets 50px; reset; the 2nd one gets 50px.

Comment: As stated, vertical-align does not work on any *inline-level element* which is an immediate sibling of an `input` element. I would like to find out why. Swap input out for another *inline-level element*, and even copy all `inputs` style properties over on the new element, and the aligning starts working as expected,

Comment: @wazz You are right. I missed that. I thought it was supposed to inhert line-height from its parent (label).

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess the specificity of `span` is greater than `label span.`

Comment: Or `form label`.

Comment: @wazz Here is an interesting development: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/zaYyER . I removed the span. It will work as long as vertical-align is applied to the input element as well (separately). Remove the vertical-align there though, and "Some label" gets stuck again.

Comment: @wazz oh, I think the culprit was a really silly HTML syntax error. I used `<input></input>`, instead of `<input>` alone. I think Temani fixed it in my OP, but I still had it wrong in the CodePen I was playing with. Seems to work like it should when I fixed that issue.

Comment: I almost changed that right away and forgot to try it... I also can't help thinking that some of the problems arise from "illegally" nested items too, fwiw.

Comment: @wazz I actually think I found a bug in CodePen, while testing this. Check this pen out: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/zaYyER. Changing vertical alignments have an immediate effect on the result (no need to force a screen refresh by changing the html). But, it you remove the vertical-align on the input, and now try to change vertical align on the label, you have to force a refresh by changing html (adding a space after an element for example), in order for the changed CSS alignment to take effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172029/discussion-between-magnus-and-wazz).

Comment: Is there still a question here, or are you now satisfied you understand the alignment of the elements?

Comment: @alohci I got it. I just don't understand why the HTML on codepen had to be refreshed for the new vertical alignment to take effect on the span. But I'll post a separate question for that, it might be a bug in CodePen or something. Thanks for input.